# Differentiation about the square root of x and y

Tags: derivatives

I stumbled across the curious question and this is how it reads:

$\sqrt x + \sqrt y = 16$

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

I squared both sides but the result is not conducive to proper differentiation.

Excuse me as I am a beginner. Please help, how to go about this sort of problems?

Comment: Hints: You could solve for $y$ by $\sqrt{y}=16-\sqrt{x}$, then square both sides.  You could also take the implicit derivative.

Comment: Do you need to do this implicitly or explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly:

You'll want to differentiate the function to $x$
$$\frac{\sqrt x}{dx} + \frac{\sqrt y}{dx} = \frac{16}{dx}$$
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{2\sqrt{y}} = 0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{x}-16}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Do it the easy way, solve for $y$:

$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=16\Longleftrightarrow\sqrt{y}=16-\sqrt{x}\Longleftrightarrow y=\left(16-\sqrt{x}\right)^2$$

Now:

$$\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(16-\sqrt{x}\right)^2=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x-32\sqrt{x}+256\right)=1-32\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+0=1-\frac{16}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $$\frac d{dx} {f(x)}^a = a{f(x)}^{a-1} \frac d{dx} f(x) $$

Comment: consider leaving a comment while you downvote!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

(1/2)x^(-1/2)+(1/2)y^(-1/2)(dy/dx)=0

(1/2)y^(-1/2)dy/dx=-(1/2)x^(-1/2)

y^(-1/2)dy/dx=-x^(-1/2)

dy/dx=-x^(-1/2)/(y^(-1/2))

Comment: Here's a link that may help you out as well. It is typically learned in calc 3, but I'll just tell you now. Let the dt become dx and differentiate it the same way. Hope it helps. <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7a6TpBt60C8>